# How to apply transactions best practice for read operations in Spring MVC using Hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions

As it is mentioned in blogs/books (e.g. Java Transactions Design Strategies by Mark Richards), read operations must have the Propagation.SUPPORTS attribute.

In a simple Spring 3.1 MVC project with Hibernate 4.1 the scenario is:

- Declarative transaction management using @Transactional
- sessionFactory of org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean
- Transaction manager of org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager
- Service class with @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
- Function of that Service class that only retrieves a resultset (performs read operation) with @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.SUPPORTS)
- Function of read operation retieves the resultset using sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get()

Of course, when a Controller executes the function of read operation, the exception "No Session found for current thread" is raised because a transaction is not started and a session is not obtained.

Based on the above configuration (while it is best e.g. non-invasive, less code etc) the Propagation.SUPPORTS attribute cannot be used unless a transaction is started before with Propagation.REQUIRED or Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW.

How do we use use Propagation.SUPPORTS for read operations without having to start a transaction e.g. with Propagation.REQUIRED before but still taking advantage the benefits of declarative transaction management?

Thank you in advance.

Coder, here is the configuration:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.myapps.service.impl" />

<bean id="txManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>.....</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${db.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I disagree with using SUPPORTS for read operations. Use REQUIRED.

- A transaction is needed anyway to perform every database operation
- Doing several small transactions to read several things at once won't benefit from the first-level cache
- There won't be any isolation between all the subsequent reads, meaning that something not visible to the first read might become visible for the second one
- you'll get lazy loading exceptions when traversing associations

Comment: JB, i am aware of the points 2,3 and 4 and thank you for mentioning them. Point 1 is what made me trying to figure this out while i was reading the suggested practice. The argument is that starting a transaction in the container is expensive especially when the operatation is only going to read whatever are the commited data at the given point in time. To my understanding, that practice says "I don't want a transaction, open a database connection and query the data". Is there a way to achieve that while we have configured declarative transaction management?

Comment: You're using a HibernateTransactionManager. This transactionManager consists in delegating the transaction to the underlying JDBC connection. Instead of getting and opening a connection 4 times, you'll just do it once. You will probably gain in performance by doing everything in a single transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Transaction is not always required for Propagation.SUPPORTS.
Propagation.SUPPORTS: Support a current transaction, execute non-transactionally if none exists.

Comment: can you please also share your context file with transaction manager configuration.

Comment: Coder, i updated the question with the configuration. Thanks.